# How to trim a part of a string, and save it in a particular string in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php

Here is my  code

```
$value = ["300","200","400","500"];

$remove = "300";
```

I want `$value` as `["200","400","500"];`

please answer to this

Comment: Your question make no sense... Could you try to explain what are you trying to do with some more context?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) as it will remove the first item in an array:

```
$value = ["300","200","400","500"];
$remove = array_shift($value);
print_r($value);
```

This will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 200
    [1] => 400
    [2] => 500
)
```

Comment: OP probably wants to remove `$remove`, not necessarily `[0]`.

Comment: True @deceze, but without clarification ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah… "string"? "Trim"? "MySQL"? … ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I would just do `$new = array_diff($value, (array) $remove);` https://3v4l.org/oDqMj that way you can supply either a string or array of values to remove.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I want to delete a value randomly not the first element in an array()

Comment: @phani you should make that clear in your question.